# Using TransformToXml on SimpleXMLElements returned by an xpath selection

Tags: php, xslt, simplexml

I want to be able to use XSLT to process the XML snippet that has been selected by XPath. When I pass the `$xmlSnippet` it behaves as though I've passed in the entire `$xml`. How do I tell the processor to work on the snippet and not on the whole file?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<FMPReport link="Summary.xml" creationTime="12:10:13 pm" creationDate="30/10/2015" type="Report" version="14.0.3">
<File name="assets.fmp12" path="server.com">
<CustomFunctionCatalog>
    <CustomFunction id="1" functionArity="1" visible="True" parameters="pageID" name="!filemakerstandards.org">
        <Calculation><![CDATA["http://filemakerstandards.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=" & pageID]]></Calculation>
    </CustomFunction>
    <CustomFunction id="2" functionArity="2" visible="True" parameters="name;value" name="#">
        <Calculation><![CDATA['example 2']]></Calculation>
    </CustomFunction>
</CustomFunctionCatalog>
</File>
</FMPReport>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="name(child::*[1])"/>
        </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

PHP

```
function displayCustomFunction($customFunctionId) {
    LIBXML_NOWARNING;
    LIBXML_NOCDATA;
    LIBXML_PARSEHUGE;
    LIBXML_BIGLINES;
    LIBXML_COMPACT;
    $filePath = 'xml/abc';
    $xslPath = 'xsl/abc';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file( $filePath, 'SimpleXMLElement');
    // ->xpath returns an array, in this case, an array of one item. array()[0] will be a SimpleXMLElement
    $xmlSnippet  = $xml->xpath('File/CustomFunctionCatalog/CustomFunction[@id=\''.$customFunctionId.'\']')[0];
    $xsl = simplexml_load_file( $xslPath, 'SimpleXMLElement');
    $xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
    $xslt->importStylesheet($xsl);
    $xslt->transformToXml($xml);        // returns 'FMPReport'
    $xslt->transformToXml($xmlSnippet); // returns 'FMPReport'. Expecting 'Calculation'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not getting any answers I've simply worked around the problem by building a string and loading it as XML.

```
$cfString = '';
foreach( $cfArray as $item){
    $cfString .= $item->asXML();
}

$cfXml = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<FMPReport>
<File name="{$fileName[0]}">
<CustomFunctionCatalog>
$cfString
</CustomFunctionCatalog>
</File>
</FMPReport>
XML;

$xml  = simplexml_load_string($cfXml);
```

and then processing with XSLT.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem >3years later with php7.3 and will use the same solution.